# How to build libcurl without curl on all platforms?

Tags: libcurl

I am using Conan-Center-index to build libcurl conan package, and can build libcurl without curl by using cmake(Set the Cmake option `BUILD_CURL_EXE` to `OFF`) on windows.

But on other platforms, libcurl was built by other ways, like autoconf. And I don't know how to use these to build libcurl without curl command line tools.

Comment: Hmm.  Do you have a question?

Comment: I want to know how to build libcurl without build the command line tools by using autoconf, not cmake